# Famo.us attaching click and touchstart events

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I'm wondering how to bind both events "click" and "touchstart" within a single line:

```
Engine.on("click"), function(){ aCode() }
Engine.on("touchstart", function(){ aCode() }
```

I expected something like this (as it is implemented in some other frameworks):

```
Engine.on("click touchstart", function(e){ aCode() });
```

My current workaround is chaining them:

```
Engine.on("click", function(){Engine.emit("touchstart")});
Engine.on("touchstart", function() { aCode() }
```

Is there a better practice for this ? The problem is that click is not caught on iOS nor the touchstart with a mouse on desktop… obviously I would like to handle the event the same way whatever the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDIT]** For handling the click and touchstart->touchend in the same way, just use the *FastClick override shim*.

just add:

```
FastClick = require('famous/inputs/FastClick');
```

then this will also work on tablet:

```
anElement.on("click", function(){alert("Click caught")})
```

**Another alternative is using this helper:**

```
function onEvent(source, events, callback)
{
    for (var event in events)
    {
        source.on(events[event], function(e) {
            callback(e);
        });
    }
}
```

Then:

```
onEvent(Famous.Engine, ["click","touchstart"],function(){});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `on()` method in Famo.us only accepts one event type. It doesn't do any jQuery style string processing to determine separate events. In theory you could have an event named `get to the chopper`

What I do when creating my custom views however is create a `bindEvents()` function which groups all the event listeners together. The only code in these handlers are other functions. If I wanted to react to two different events in the same way, I'd just use the same function for both of them.

```
// An example Class demonstrating events - some off-topic parts omitted
function myLovelyHorseButton() {

    // Recomended Reading: https://famo.us/guides/dev/events.html

    this._eventInput = new EventHandler();
    this._eventOutput = new EventHandler();

    this._eventInput.pipe(this.sync);
    this.sync.pipe(this._eventInput);

    EventHandler.setInputHandler(this, this._eventInput);
    EventHandler.setOutputHandler(this, this._eventOutput);

    /** Set options & variables
    /* ...
    */

    // create event listeners for this specific instance
    _bindEvents.call(this);
};

// bind all the events for the button
function _bindEvents() {
    //Call event handlers with this set to owner.
    this._eventInput.bindThis(this);
    // listen for events
    this._eventInput.on('click', _handleClick);
    this._eventInput.on('touchstart', _handleClick);    //Same as 'click'
};

//  Nay to the console on click/touch
function _handleClick(event) {
    console.log('Nayyyyy!!!');
};


// create an instance of myLovelyHorseButton
var button = new myLovelyHorseButton;

// We would then add the button to the Render Tree
mainContext.add(button);
```

There is a big reason why you don't want to do the chaining pattern you're currently using. And that's because by emitting a touchstart event on a click, you're inferring that there's going to be some code there to act upon it. One day you might get drunk and decide *"Nobody on touch devices is using this!"* and delete the `ontouchstart` handler. And in an instant, your code doesn't work for anybody, touch or mouse.

**TL;DR** There is nothing wrong with using multiple `on()` calls.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It helps but could you extend your example to the touch and click case ? I hardly get when and how to use the _bindEvents() method.

Comment: I've edited the example to show how a class would handle events in Famo.us. If you we just building UI's with individual surfaces you would simply be doing `mysurface.on('click', clickHandler());`

Comment: Another thing. I don't understand why you want the Engine to listen for click & touch events. The engine isn't something the end user sees  on screen.

Comment: actually the "Engine" will be a "Surface" most of the time, giving an example with it was shorter than a "Surface" one.